# I can't get my soundcard running with Ubuntu Studio

Tags: soundcard, ubuntu-studio

I have a Dell XPS 8500 and I'm running an Ubuntu Studio virtually. The installation went well except for my soundcard. I can't get my soundcard installed in Ubuntu Studio. So making music or listening to music or watching movies or creating movies is not possible. Can anybody help me with this? I already searched the internet but haven't found an answer to my question. Can someone help me with this. I would like to try Ubuntu Studio for making music and video's.

Answer (score 0):

Try gnome-alsamixer. Here is what do I do. I have integrated soundcard and Audigy.

1. Install Ubuntu Studio (not virtually).
2. Switch off the integrated soundcard in BIOS.
3. Launch terminal. Type "sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer". After the program is installed type "gnome-alsamixer".
4. Select "Audigy Analog/Digital Output Jack".
5. Enjoy)

---

Note: I've written Select "Audigy Analog/Digital Output Jack". You must select analog of your soundcard.